# How to swap regions in bitmap

Tags: android

ex.:

I have a bitmap size 500x500. And on this bitmap I have coordinates to 2 regions.
one region is at X=10, Y=10, size 10x10
second region is at X=400, Y=400, size 10x10

What would be the best way to swap those two regions in the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it trough Canvas.

Something like:

```
Bitmap swapped = Bitmap.createBitmap(origin.getWidth(), origin.getHeight(), origin.getConfig());
Canvas drawer = new Canvas(swapped);
drawer.drawBitmap(origin, new Rect(0,0,100,100), new Rect(100,100,100,100), paint);
drawer.drawBitmap(origin, new Rect(100,100,100,100), new Rect(0,0,100,100), paint);
```

At that point your 'swapped' Bitmap will have the origin pieces drawed in different regions.

For more see the Canvas documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Matrix, android.graphics.Paint)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, a simple "cruel" approach can do the work:

Load the bitmap in an 2-dimensional array and swap your cells.

It will take roughly around: 500x500x4 bytes which is a bit less than a 1 mega-byte of memory, which is nothing for android phones nowdays since app have at least 8/16 mgb of ram at their use.(on weaker phones)

Also the operations will be quite fast, even if you do a bunch of processing of the bit maps, such as resizing and so on.....

If you wont best performance you can use native code, there are some libraries for processing bitmaps that are quite memory and cpu efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be the same as switching any type of data:

- make a temporary bitmap to hold area1 data and put there the data.
- put area2 data into area1.
- put the temporary bitmap data into area2 , and recycle the temporary bitmap.

Here's a sample code that I've written. It's not tested, but should work:

```
Bitmap origin=...;
Rect r1=...,r2=... ; //assumption: both rectangles are of the same size
//copy from region1 to temp bitmap
Bitmap temp= Bitmap.createBitmap(origin,r1.left,r1.top,r1.width(),r1.height());
//copy from region2 into region1 
Canvas canvas=new Canvas(origin);
canvas.drawBitmap(origin, r2, r1, new Paint());
//copy from temp bitmap to region2 
canvas.drawBitmap(temp, new Rect(0,0,r2.width(),r2.height()), r2, paint);
temp.recycle();
```

An alternative way (which might be better in terms of speed and/or memory) would be to use int array instead of a new bitmap object, but I think this method is easy to understand.

Here's the alternative:

```
Bitmap origin=...;
Rect r1=...,r2=... ; //assumption: both rectangles are of the same size
//copy from region1 to temp pixels
int[] pixels=new int[r1.width()*r1.height()];
origin.getPixels ( pixels, 0, origin.getWidth(), r1.left, r1.top, r1.width(), r1.height());
//copy from region2 into region1 
Canvas canvas=new Canvas(origin);
canvas.drawBitmap(origin, r2, r1, new Paint());
//copy from temp pixels to region2
origin.setPixels (pixels, 0, origin.getWidth(), r2.left, r2.top, r2.width(), r2.height());
```

I hope I didn't make any mistakes here, since I haven't tested it.